# Can I recalculate the energy of an awkward array of Vectors by declaring a new mass value?

Tags: python, awkward-array

My question is about the `Vector` module in scikit-hep.

https://vector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I have an `awkward` array of `vector`s and I'd like to set the mass of all of them to be a common value. For example, I can do this with a single `vector` object.

```
x = vector.obj(pt=2, eta=1.5, phi=1, energy=10)
y = x.from_rhophietatau(rho=x.rho, eta=x.eta, phi=x.phi, tau=20)

print(f"{x.mass:6.3f}  {x.pt}  {x.eta}  {x.phi}  {x.energy:6.2f}")
print(f"{y.mass:6.3f}  {y.pt}  {y.eta}  {y.phi}  {y.energy:6.2f}")
```

Output

```
 8.824  2  1.5  1   10.00
20.000  2  1.5  1   20.55
```

But suppose I want to do this with an `awkward` array of vectors?

Let me start with some starter code from this previous question:

[Using awkward-array with zip/unzip with two different physics objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834275/using-awkward-array-with-zip-unzip-with-two-different-physics-objects/72834871)

First, I'll get an input file

```
curl http://opendata.cern.ch/record/12361/files/SMHiggsToZZTo4L.root --output SMHiggsToZZTo4L.root
```

Then I'll make use of the code from the answer to that question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

import uproot
import awkward as ak

import vector
vector.register_awkward()


infile = uproot.open("/tmp/SMHiggsToZZTo4L.root")

muon_branch_arrays = infile["Events"].arrays(filter_name="Muon_*")
electron_branch_arrays = infile["Events"].arrays(filter_name="Electron_*")

muons = ak.zip({
    "pt": muon_branch_arrays["Muon_pt"],
    "phi": muon_branch_arrays["Muon_phi"],
    "eta": muon_branch_arrays["Muon_eta"],
    "mass": muon_branch_arrays["Muon_mass"],
    "charge": muon_branch_arrays["Muon_charge"],
}, with_name="Momentum4D")

quads = ak.combinations(muons, 4)
mu1, mu2, mu3, mu4 = ak.unzip(quads)

p4 = mu1 + mu2 + mu3 + mu4
```

The type of `p4` is `<class 'vector._backends.awkward_.MomentumArray4D'>`. Is there a way to set *all* the masses of the `p4` objects to be, for example, 125? While this is not exactly my analysis, I need to do something similar where I will then use `p4` to boost the `muX` objects to the CM frame of `p4` and look at some relative angles. But I need to set the mass of `p4` to be a constant value.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well written question, thank you for the effort!

The answer here is yes, you can set a new value for the mass! One would do this updating the `mass` field using `ak.with_field`, or using the subscript `__setitem__` operator, e.g.

```py
p4['mass'] = 125.0
```

This will internally call `ak.with_field`, which you could also use e.g.

```py
p4 = ak.with_field(p4, 125.0, "mass")
```

and broadcasts the `125.0` value against the rest of the array.

It is sometimes more convenient to use the `vector` Awkward constructors, as it is slightly less typing:

```py
muons = vector.zip({
    'pt': muon_branch_arrays['Muon_pt'],
    'phi': muon_branch_arrays['Muon_phi'],
    'eta': muon_branch_arrays['Muon_eta'],
    'charge': muon_branch_arrays['Muon_charge'],
    'mass': muon_branch_arrays['Muon_mass'],
})
```

`vector` determines what kind of array you are building from the field names. This provides a good opportunity to highlight something important: `vector` supports *aliases* for fields, e.g. `tau` ↔ `mass`. If you compare the fields of the `muons` array above with the `array` you built with `ak.zip`, you'll notice that my `muons` array has fields `['rho', 'phi', 'eta', 'tau', 'charge']` whilst your muon array has fields `['pt', 'phi', 'eta', 'mass', 'charge']`. What's happening here is that `vector` is *canonicalising* the field names. This means that, were you to build an array in this manner, you'd want to use `p4['tau'] = 125.0` instead of `p4['mass'] = 125.0`.

This would also be apparent if you transformed your `muons` array in any way, e.g. `double_muons = muons + muons`. You'd find that the result loses the `charge` field, and has `tau` instead of `mass` and `rho` instead of `pt`. So, something to be mindful of if you need to set a field.

The reason that `p4['mass'] = 125` works, but `pt['mass'][:] = 125` does not is because of how Awkward Array is designed. Whilst Awkward Arrays are immutable, this is only half of the story. You can already see that there is some kind of mutability - we can modify a field in-place. This works because, whilst the underlying "layouts" from which `Array`s are built do not allow users to modify their values, the high level `ak.Array` can be given a new layout. This is what `__setitem__` does under the hood, i.e. https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward/blob/72c9edd55b9c4611ffc46952cda4cf9920a91315/src/awkward/highlevel.py#L1062-L1063

Comment: Ah, thank you for this detailed explanation! I think what I want to do is update the `tau` field, as that causes the `energy` to be recalculated, which is what I want. 

However this means that I can have a vector with `mass` as one value and `tau` as a different value. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: I edited my answer at one point, so do check the website (here) if you've been following the replies over email. I originally alluded to this more directly, but my revised answer instead explains the cause of the field name discrepancies. 

You should be able to use `mass` and `tau` interchangeably - as long as you only ever have one of these fields set on your array. If you set `mass` and your vector instead only has the `tau` field (you can check this with `p4.fields`), you'll run into this conflict.

Comment: Note that any operation on your vector that returns a new vector object e.g. addition may change the fields (by canonicalising the aliases, and dropping any unknown fields e.g. `charge`)

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to explain this! 

I think I'm getting it now. For my particular case, I want to make sure I `ak.with_field(...)` with `tau`. When I do, I see both the `tau` and `mass` fields update (along with `energy` and `t`, natch).  If I use `ak.with_field(...)` with `mass`, I do not see the fields update because (I know this is oversimplifying things, so forgive me) the `tau`, `rho`, etc. are the *real* fields storing the information of the geometric vector and `mass`, `pt`, etc are aliased "helper" fields for standard physics-speak. Close enough?  :)

Comment: Nearly! I've read the source, and I think I'd advise just using `tau` for mass instead of `mass`. The reason for this is that I believe aliases like `mass` are transformed to their canonical equivalents quite frequently at the moment, so for ease of use it might be better to switch over to `tau`.

What you're observing is that `p4` has different fields to `mu1`. This is because the addition operation changes the fields.

In future I would assume that vector will be modified to preserve the aliases where possible.

Comment: To further concrete my response above: in theory, `mass` and `tau` are equally legitimate "real" fields. At the moment, however, vector converts `mass` to `tau` in certain contexts.

Comment: Rockin'. Thanks Angus!